# Higher Dimensional analogue to translation and rotation.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Is there a higher dimensional analogue to translation and rotation. Translation occurs along an axis, and rotations occurs along a plane. Is there some isometry that occurs along a 3-plane (hyperplane?) and does it have a name? Do these isometries generalize well? That is, are there $\binom{N}{n}$ different $n$-dimension isometries in $N$ space where a rotation would be a 2-dimension isometry?

Comment: Are you assuming we're working with the Euclidean metric then?

Comment: How does this make a difference? I'm asking purely out of curiosity because I am really intrigued that this makes a difference to the answer!

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference or not; I haven't looked into this much. It seems to generalize this way, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space), which makes sense. Any rotation can be represented by an orthogonal matrix, and you can construct $4\times 4$ orthogonal matrices that have two independent eigenvectors with real eigvenvalues.

Comment: Check out [Quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). Quaternion multiplication is rotation in $4$ dimensions similar to how complex multiplication is rotation in $2$ dimensions.  
This can be generalized to $n$ dimensions using matrices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rotations can occur in $n$-dimensions in the same way. For example, you can have rotation on a sphere, for the case $n = 3$.

In general, these $n$-dimensional rotations are characterized by elements of the *special orthogonal group*, denoted $SO(n)$, which consist of the set of $n \times n$ matrices $Q$ such that $Q^T Q = I$ and $\det(Q) = 1$. For any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, acting such a rotation on $x$ is given by considering the matrix-vector product $Qx$.

If you want such a rotation $Q$ to have as part of its behavior rotation when restricted to some $2$-dimensional plane, then you just want a $Q = Q_1 \oplus Q_2$, where $Q_1$ is a $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix.